# C# Opening a Modal Form in a class with background worker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm trying to create a class, that can be used anywhere, that runs a background worker process, which if running, will open a modal form that shows it's progress and other forms aren't usable but having difficulty working it out. Thought I might be able to do the following, but doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

I might be going completely the wrong way about it, but here is my cut down code:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        // load the database
        Database.Load(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

namespace Blah.Common
{
public static class Database
{
    private static Progress progressForm = new Progress();
    public static void Load(Form parentForm)
    {
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        bw.DoWork += (obj, e) => bw_DoWork(parentForm);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private static void bw_DoWork(Form parentForm)
    {
        progressForm.ShowDialog(parentForm);
        progressForm.UpdateLabel("Loading...");

        doHeavyProcess();
        progressForm.Dispose()
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowDialog() is a blocking call, the BGW will not be able to continue running until you close the dialog.

Displaying UI on a worker thread is **always** wrong with a long lasting effect on your program that will make it hang randomly in a [very undiagnosable way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  You must create the progress dialog in your UI thread, after the RunWorkerAsync() call.  Update it with the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: Of course! I tried putting the showdialog before the bw stuff, and it obviously failed because it had to wait for me to close it to continue. I didn't think of putting it AFTER the RunWorkerAsync.

If I have the form being closed in the bw_RunWorkerCompleted, then everything else will continue.